# Why does the number of returned samples where name='keyword' does not match the number of observed samples with 'keyword' in table?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have a Postgres table whose header is `[id(uuid), name(str), arg_name(str), measurements(list), run_id(uuid), parent_id(uuid)]` with a total of 237K entries.

When I want to filter for specific measurements I can use 'name', but for the majority of entries in the table 'name' == 'arg_name' and thus map to the same sample.

In my peculiar case I am interested in retrieving samples whose 'name'='TimeM12nS' and whose 'arg_name'='Time'. These two attributes point to the same samples when visually inspecting the table through PgAdmin. That is to say all entries which have arg_name='Time' also have the name='TimeM12nS' and vice-versa.

Its obvious there's a problem because of the quantity of returned samples is not the same. I first noticed the problem using django orm, but the problem is also present when I query the DB using PgAdmin.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE name='TimeM12nS'
```

returns 301 entries (name='TimeM12nS' and arg_name='Time' in all cases)

BUT the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE arg_name='Time'
```

returns 3945 (name='TimeM12nS' and arg_name='Time' in all cases)

I am completely stumped, anyone think they can shed some light into what's happening here?

EDIT:
I should add that the query by 'arg_name' returns the 301 entries that are returned when querying by 'name'

Comment: 'Visual inspection' is not very robust.  Both because there can be invisible characters, and because it is tedious and humans are error prone.  Select specifically for `not name='TimeM12nS' and arg_name='Time' `

Comment: @jjanes how would I inspect for invisible characters?

Comment: @rdmtinez -  You can use a regex for only printable characters.

Comment: "*That is to say all entries which have arg_name='Time' also have the name='TimeM12nS' and vice-versa*" - well, apparently this is not the case. Otherwise, you'd get two identical results.

Comment: @jjanes your suggestion also returns zero entries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , it sounds unintuitive, I know, but indeed that is the case, hence why I'm stumped.

Comment: What does `SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE (arg_name='Time' and name <> 'TimeM12nS') OR  (arg_name <> 'Time' and name = 'TimeM12nS')` return?

Comment: I tend to believe Postgres here, not your claim that they should be the same.

Comment: @jarlh it returns and empty query

Comment: try re-indexing the columns

Comment: Try something like `SELECT DISTINCT '[' + name + ']' FROM TableA WHERE arg_name='Time'` (or whatever the concatenation operator is in Postgres). Trying to see whether there are extra spaces in the value

Answer (score 1):

First let me say thank you to everyone who pitched in ideas to solve this conundrum and especially to [JGH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635569/jgh) for the solution (found in the comments of the original post).

Indeed the problem was a indexing issue. After re-indexing the queries return the same number of entries '3945' as expected.

In Postgress re-indexing a table can be achieved through pgAdmin by navigating to `Databases > 'database_name' > Schemas > Tables` then `right-clicking` on the `table_name` selecting  `Maintenance` and pressing the `REINDEX` button.

or more simply by running the following command

`REINDEX TABLE table_name`

[Postgress Re-Indexing Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the database, it's not possibly to give a definitive answer. All I can provide is the next query that I would use in this case.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), LENGTH(name), name, arg_name
FROM TableA
WHERE arg_name='Time'
GROUP BY name, arg_name;
```

This should show you any differences in the name column that you aren't able to see. The length of that string could also be informative.

Comment: Thank you @UncleCarl there's only one entry where length is 9 as it should be as does the corresponding entry for the query where name=TimeM12nS. The counts also match the discrepancy 3945, 301 respectively. Indeed the strings are the same but Postgres doesn't seem to think so

Comment: @rdmtinez Interesting. So, you are saying that you get two rows from that query, both with length of 9 and showing the same 9 characters? Ouch. This doesn't seem to make sense (you already knew that :-).

Comment: one row per query, 1) `WHERE arg_name='Time'` 2) `WHERE name='TimeM12nS'`  because indeed the strings are the same as they should be. I even went to the source files from which these objects are created and there's nothing different in them either. I will try re-indexing as @JGH suggested in the comments of the original post.

Comment: But what do you get when you do the group by? How many rows and what are all the values?